# Can't find SttpBackends + "Error occurred in an application involving default arguments."

Tags: scala, syntax, telegram

I'm trying to create a extremely simple Telegram bot in Scala using [`bot4s`](https://github.com/bot4s/telegram). I'm pretty much following the example there. Here's the [code](https://github.com/JJ/BoBot):

```
package info.jjmerelo.BoBot

import cats.instances.future._
import cats.syntax.functor._

import com.bot4s.telegram.api.RequestHandler
import com.bot4s.telegram.api.declarative.Commands
import com.bot4s.telegram.clients.{FutureSttpClient, ScalajHttpClient}
import com.bot4s.telegram.future.{Polling, TelegramBot}

import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.Future

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger


object BoBot extends TelegramBot
    with Polling
    with Commands[Future] {

  implicit val backend = SttpBackends.default
  def token = sys.env("BOBOT_TOKEN")
  override val client: RequestHandler[Future] = new FutureSttpClient(token)
  val log = Logger("BoBot")
//  val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("hitos.json").mkString
//  val hitos = JSON.parseFull( lines )
//  val solo_hitos = hitos.getOrElse( hitos )

  onCommand("hey") { implicit msg =>
    log.info("Hello")
    reply("Conseguí que funcionara").void
  }
}
```

And here's the `build.sbt`

```
name := "bobot"

version := "0.0.1"

organization := "info.jjmerelo"

libraryDependencies += "com.bot4s" %% "telegram-core" % "4.4.0-RC2"

val circeVersion = "0.12.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"
).map(_ % circeVersion)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2"
retrieveManaged := true
```

> Circe is for later

Anyway, I managed to compile most of it, but I still get these two errors:

```
[info] compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/jmerelo/Asignaturas/cloud-computing/BoBot/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/jmerelo/Asignaturas/cloud-computing/BoBot/src/main/scala/info/jjmerelo/BoBot.scala:21:26: not found: value SttpBackends
[error]   implicit val backend = SttpBackends.default
[error]                          ^
[error] /home/jmerelo/Asignaturas/cloud-computing/BoBot/src/main/scala/info/jjmerelo/BoBot.scala:23:49: could not find implicit value for parameter backend: com.softwaremill.sttp.SttpBackend[scala.concurrent.Future,Nothing]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]   override val client: RequestHandler[Future] = new FutureSttpClient(token)
[error]                                                 ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed 11 nov. 2020 8:19:38
```

I can't figure out either of the two. SttpBackends is missing, that's clear, but there's nothing in the example that indicates it's needed, or, for that matter, what library should be included. The second one about the default arguments I simply can't figure it out, even if I define `token` as String or if I change `def` to `val`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error messages is associated with each other.
First error tells us that compiler couldn't find object `SttpBackends` which has field of `SttpBackend`.
The second one tells us that compiler couldn't find `implicit backend: SttpBackend` for constructing `FutureSttpClient`. It requires two implicits: `SttpBackend` and `ExecutionContext`.

```
class FutureSttpClient(token : _root_.scala.Predef.String, 
  telegramHost : _root_.scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ })
  (implicit backend : com.softwaremill.sttp.SttpBackend[scala.concurrent.Future, scala.Nothing], 
    ec : scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) 
  extends com.bot4s.telegram.clients.SttpClient[scala.concurrent.Future] {...}
```

You can create it by yourself as in [bot4s examples](https://github.com/bot4s/telegram/blob/f3cfbe1f11471791e2c499244f3ce1b166af0777/examples/src-jvm/SttpBackends.scala).

If you will try to find `SttpBackends` object in **bot4s** library you would found this code in [bot4s examples](https://github.com/bot4s/telegram/blob/f3cfbe1f11471791e2c499244f3ce1b166af0777/examples/src-jvm/SttpBackends.scala):

```
import com.softwaremill.sttp.okhttp._

object SttpBackends {
  val default: SttpBackend[Future, Nothing] = OkHttpFutureBackend()
}
```

add this object to your project to make it compilable.